# How to extend/resize Root ("/") partition if there is no unallocated space available?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ssd

Since there is no unallocated memory available at present, I need to first create some unallocated memory from of one the partitions (`/dev/nvme0n1p3`, `/dev/nvme0m1p4`, `/dev/nvme0n1p5`, `/dev/nvme0n1p8`). Then, I need to make that memory available either at the beginning or end of the root partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p7`). After that, I have to extend / resize the root partition (as it is almost full).

[image: Image of the disk partition using GParted]

Now, how to perform all of the operations without losing any of the data or formatting whole system?

Comment: The magic word is "Backup"...

Comment: [pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) this does not answer my question specifically. I want to first resize the external partitions and then create unallocated memory, which needs to be moved near root partition. And I want to do this without losing my data or formating whole external partiions.

Comment: [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat) This also does not answer my question. More or less, their solution is to have a backup and then delete the portion adjacent to the root partition. But this is not what I wish to do.

Comment: [mook765](https://askubuntu.com/users/590937/mook765) Yeah, this is a solution, not not I want. First take a backup and then remodel the whole setup like installing a new OS.

Comment: Any of those that you resize you would need to move them after resizing them so that you can move the unallocated space to after of your root `/dev/nvme0n1p7`.  Then you can resize your root partition.  There is ALWAYS a risk of data loss when messing with partitions, so backups are strongly recommended.  Your process will take time, but it can be done.  This should be done also in a Live environment like a Live USB / DVD.  Do not move the EFI or the Microsoft Resevered partitions as that could make it non-bootable.

Comment: @Terrance, [How to Resize your Ubuntu Partitions?](https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/#:~:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20right%2Dclick,partition%20into%20the%20unallocated%20space.) mentions that _Using GParted, if I move the start sector of the Ubuntu partition containing  /boot directory – likely my primary Ubuntu partition – my OS may fail to boot. If I'm moving the start sector of my main Ubuntu partition, I’ll likely have to reinstall Grub 2 afterwards._

Comment: @Terrance, so, if I create a partition of unallocated memory before _/dev/nvme0n1p8_ (~20 GB) & extend the root partition (_/dev/nvme0n1p7_) from the end sector instead of start sector, will my OS fail to boot & if I have to reinstall the Grub 2?Also, if I create unallocated partitions at the start/end of _/dev/nvme0n1p3_ and _/dev/nvme0n1p5_, how to move these partitions at the end of root partition? Because, if I move these partitions, then the addresses of the root partition (or its start sector) and other partitions may change and I will find same issues of boot failure, etc.

Comment: If you take from /dev/nvme0n1p8 then move it (nvme0n1p8) to the end of the free space, that will create your free space between /dev/nvme0n1p7 and /dev/nvme0n1p8.  Then all you would have to do is resize /dev/nvme0n1p7.  No moving of /dev/nvme0n1p7 is required at that point.  If the boot gets broken, which is always a possibility, there is a boot repair that can fix that for you.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But with only resizing my bet would be on boot actually still working after resize.